# Give child modules access to parent provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am trying to set a provider that would be called on each module individually so that it may have access to the provider.

I have a parent ng-app bootstrapped around everything , then inside I can call separate modules. My initial approach was to have a factory in the parent app module (and this works great), however I would like each module be able to .config itself to this provider so it may send their own variables each time to be handled by the provider. My issue is being able to give the children modules access to the parent provider.

So i have my parent app and provider like so :

```
 angular.
 module('urlTesting', [
'urlTesting.moduleOne',
'urlTesting.moduleTwo'
])
.provider('statepls', function() { 

});
```

and it's bootstrapped onto the body with ng-app and the children (module one and module 2 are injected into it).

then in the child module I inject the parent like so

```
 angular.
  module('urlTesting.moduleOne', [
    'urlTesting.moduleOneCtrl',
    'moduleOne.directive',
    'urlTesting'
  ]).config(function(){

});
```

I can use factories from the parent module, however it seems i cant use the config to set some variables, as when I try to do this :

```
   angular.
  module('urlTesting.moduleOne', [
'urlTesting.moduleOneCtrl',
'moduleOne.directive',
'urlTesting'
 ]).config(function(stateplsProvider){

 });
```

I get an  -

```
  Unknown provider: stateplsProvider
```

So maybe it can't see providers before the run phase from the parent module? Or perhaps I am injecting these wrong.

My goal is to set a provider on the parent module that all the subsequent modules would then have access to and be able to set some stuff with .config in each module. Could use some help wrapping my head around this, I can't seem to get this working. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a circular reference exception? I see you are importing the parent module on the child module. In the submodule you just request the parent provider to be injected in the config. If the parent module has not been bootstraped (eg testing) you should provide a default provider implementation in the module itself

Comment: An even better design could be to create a third module that has the provider and inject this into both other modules.

Comment: @mxa055 that's what I ended up doing!